# Memory storage across languages

Tags: c++, ruby, memory-management, stack, heap-memory

I'm new to programming and recently found out about how the storage of objects and variables in some languages worked (c++,java,...). But when I read (in random sites) about how storage worked in other languages such as ruby, apparently the concept of stack doesn't exist and the objects and variables are saved in the heap. Is this true?

If so, then do segments like the stack or (.data,.bss for other languages) not exist physically? how does the storage work? I can't quite understand memory segments.

Edit: I'm not asking about the memory segments on every language, im just aaking why does a segment exists in a language and in another it doesnt. ( do segments not exist physically as... Segments? Like different sections of the RAM)

Comment: All you can guarantee among most languages is that the variables can hold values.  There is no guarantee where in memory the values are held or if the values are even placed in memory (they could be placed in processor registers or other hardware devices).

Comment: What you "found out recently" just scratches the surface. But as your question is now, a proper answer would fill many books. You should read existing literature a bit more, and if necessary ask a more narrow question later.

Comment: @deviantfan then, could you point me to some book or relevant piece of literature please? I can't understand yet why it is a broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ruby Language Specification does not say anything about a stack and/or a heap. Whether or not a particular Ruby implementation happens to use a heap, a stack, both, or neither is completely up to the implementor.

Typically, a Ruby implementation will use one heap per process, one stack per thread, and one lightweight stack per fibre, but that is a private internal implementation detail of the particular Ruby implementation and is not exposed to the programmer and is not guaranteed in any way, i.e. it may change at any time without notice. It is also not true for all implementations. MagLev has a single distributed persistent heap for all processes (and all computers) in a MagLev cluster. Cardinal has no stack(s), it uses continuations which are allocated on the heap. I believe SmallRuby uses a single Spaghetti stack for all threads.

Note that this is not unusual. For example, the C# Language Specification doesn't say anything about heap or stack either. Neither do the Java Language Specification or the C++ Standard.

Comment: Neither does the C++ standard.